# How to add scrolling parallax effect to a text

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to add parallax effect on text while scrolling from top to bottom and bottom to top.
Suppose if we need a text dissappear while reaching at perticular position while scrolling a web page from top to bottom and vice versa.how to get such effect?Thank you

Comment: check this out: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/

Comment: Can i use animate.css to achieve it.any working example much more appritiated.thank you

Comment: [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) is sooo cool! I just discovered it because of you! **BUT** is completely another bank of effects. Compared to [Parallax](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/).

Answer (score 1):

I Just commented under the question...
And I realized that it was THE answer (with a short explanation).

You mention [Parallax](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/), but you talk about [Animate](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in comments.
So your question may now be «What's the difference?

Between the two, Differences are:
- the scripting langage
- the object type it affects

One is for html elements like strings or boxes (2 dimensions «twist» in order to look like 3d effect).
The other if for multiple-layer images, z-indexed (3 dimensions effect)

Both solutions have their use.
:)